# ios - Injecting text into a UIWebView textField

Tags: javascript, ios, webforms, uitextfield

Quick question - if a textfield in a webform, does not automatically has the focus set by the form, ie you got to press the field before the keyboard pops up - am I correct to assume that field cannot be edited then?

In other words - I cannot set a text for a textField by injecting javascript into it, unless it gets a focus upon loading of the website right?

NOTE: I am **not** talking about set texts or placeholders here:-)

Cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can! You can use Javascript to set the value:

```
[theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('textFieldID').value = 'MyText'"]
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089809/set-text-for-a-textfield-in-uiwebview) an article which shows you how to set and get the values of textfields with Javascript.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Ok I am taking another crack at it - do I put it in this method? : '- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{' ??

Comment: Well, if you want to change the text "upon the loading of the website," then yes, put your method into - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{ so that the method is called once your webview is ready to go!