# Displaying ViewController when textField in UIWebView is pressed

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I've never actually worked with a `UIWebView` before, so I'm not really sure where to begin. Effectively I'm working with a developer who's building this web platform for the app I'm currently working on. The user is supposed to fill in a form in the `WebView`. One of the fields is for a destination for a ticket they want to purchase. In the app, we already have a `ViewController` which is nicely laid out, allowing users to either enter a custom destination or choose from a predefined list. Would it be possible to display this `ViewController` when the text field in the WebView is clicked? The field then fills with the selected destination when the user has finished. Is there a better way of doing this (without putting load on the web Developer) and I'm just being stupid?

Like I said, I've never really worked with a UIWebView in this way before as I normally like to make my apps 100% native, but here is a go at how I imagine it may work:

```
-(void)someMethodThatsCalledWhenTextFieldIsPressed {
    AttachDestinationViewController *vc = [[AttachDestinationViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And then in the AttachDestinationViewController we would do something like:

```
-(void)didFinish {
    CustomUIWebViewClass *parentViewController = (CustomUIWebViewClass *)self.parentViewController;
    parentViewController.propertyForTextField.text = self.locationEntered.text;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

That's how I would envision it if it were a normal ViewController, however, I have absolutely no idea how we would call `-(void)someMethodThatsCalledWhenTextFieldIsPressed`, nor how we would create `propertyForTextField` for the textField in the UIWebView.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Regards, 
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to add a button to your `UIWebView`

Something like:

```
<a href="#" class="buttonStyle">Click me!</a>
```

Execute custom code by clicking on a link(button) in html

Then implement `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`.

You button links should look like this:

```
<a href="button://dosomething" class="buttonStyle">Click me!</a>
```

Now implement `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` like this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
    // only do something if a link has been clicked...
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {     

            // check if the url requests starts with our custom protocol:
        if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"button://"]) 
        {
            [self CallYourMethodButton];
            return NO;
        } 
    }

    return YES;
}
```

This method will detect the href button you clicked according to the title and here you can call the method for your button.

**EDIT :**

Well Mike then its just like entering data to and from a form right ? Then you need to get the element name or the element id for the textfield. Please go through the following links :-

[Finding and auto-filling HTML login forms in a UIWebView using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715100/finding-and-auto-filling-html-login-forms-in-a-uiwebview-using-javascript)

[ios - Injecting text into a UIWebView textField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505585/ios-injecting-text-into-a-uiwebview-textfield)

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves the first part of the problem (+1), but what about going back from the VC to the WebView, passing the value from the former to the latter? Mike.