How can I use javascript/html DOM to change the value of a textfield (injecting from iOS app)?
I'm an iOS Developer. In our app (Xcode, UIKit) I've created a web view that displays our help centre website. Then, whenever a user loads the help centre and navigates to the page for submitting a new ticket, I want the new ticket text field to autofill some user-specific info (app version, email, etc.). My problem is that I cannot get the details I want to appear in the text area.
enter image description
I've added the following method which is called when the ticket page loads:
    func populateTicketBody() {                  

    let ticketDetails = "Hello"
    let javascript = """
        var textArea = 
        document.getElementById('helpdesk_ticket_ticket_body_attributes_description_html');
             
            if (textArea) {
             document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';             
                textArea.placeholder = 'hi \(ticketDetails)';
                 textArea.innerHTML = 'Hi';             
                textArea.textContent = 'Hi';             
                textArea.value = 'Hi';         
            }
         """         
    helpWebView.evaluateJavaScript(javascript, completionHandler: nil)
     }  

I'm totally new to injecting javascript to modify html, this is my first time trying the above, and I'm struggling to see where I'm going wrong. The colour change is successful, which means the code is working to an extent and textArea is a valid element. Then I've tried 'textContent', 'value', and 'innerHTML' to edit the textarea text but nothing works. I tried changing placeholder as a test, and that doesn't work either.
I'm wondering if I'm referencing the wrong element? If that's the case, I'm struggling to find the correct id for this text area. Am I modifying the wrong attribute? Is there an extra step I've missed? Please see a screenshot of the html below. Many TIA.
enter image description here

Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10505615/833395
